# Can an instance of a `ref struct` be moved by the GC?

Tags: c#

It's my understanding that a `ref struct` may only live on the stack, but can the stack itself be moved by the GC? What about the stacks of managed threads?

```cs
Foo foo = new();
ref var fooRef = ref foo;
Foo * ptr;
fixed (Foo* p = &fooRef)
    ptr = p;

// Could `ptr` be invalid here?
// Even though we know that `Foo` won't move because it's
// guaranteed to be on the stack? Or can stack addresses move?
// Maybe the GC could move the entire thread and therefore its stack?


ref struct Foo {}
```

I think the core question is possibly: Can the GC move the stack itself?

EDIT: I found this reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/137s9hv/taking_the_address_of_a_ref_struct_without_fixed/

EDIT 2: For context, here's the code I'm working on. It's a stack-only tree. The pointer is needed because C# doesn't currently allow a ref struct to contain a ref field of its own type.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

#pragma warning disable CS8500

readonly unsafe ref struct TreeNode<T>
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly TreeNode<T> * parent;
    public readonly T Value;

    public TreeNode(T value) => Value = value;
    public TreeNode(T value, in TreeNode<T> parent) : this(value)
    {
        fixed (TreeNode<T> * ptr = &parent)
            this.parent = ptr;
    }

    public Boolean HasParent => parent != null;
    public ref TreeNode<T> Parent => ref *parent;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm really mistaken, NO. The GC only moves reference type objects in order to reduce fragmentation during collection operations. Stacks never move. They get allocated when the thread is created an are there for the life of the thread

Comment: Why do you need a `fixed` pointer anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really look at your code, only your question. What are you trying to do. I've been using tye Framework since before it shipped, other than P/Invoke and related interop things, I've never used `fixed`

Comment: Makes no sense to have tree nodes being stack-based ref structs, these should be reference types instead.

Comment: Suffice to say: unless you are *sure* that all nodes will always remain on the stack (for example you are using `stackalloc` and have not ended the function) this code is highly dangerous. Stack data is not moved, but it will be overwritten at the end of any given function. You are probably better off just storing an `int` offset into an array (or stack-allocated Span)

Comment: Put it another way: what code do you have that *uses* this tree? If it is creating it using a loop reusing the same variable then this code will definitely not work.

Comment: `ref struct`s are absolutely useful and valid. Many people use them often to minimize memory allocations. If you don't use them, that's fine. Please don't suggest that those who do should use a different language, or that their use cases are unfathomable, or that they represent an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried your code, you will find that the compiler will display an error in `&foo`:

> [CS0213](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0213?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0213)): You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression

Which precisely answers your question: the `ref struct` variable on the stack is always fixed.

---

UPDATE: At [the IL level](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANmgExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChyBmAAgFcA7AZwEMAzGCyosAwiwDeDAJDlqSFgDEIEAFQsAsgApsHDC2wBKaZPosz5s0ogs+ylgF4WHGAHdNBifodeAvgG5pKVg+FgA3HigbZQAlGBDHYKiIANMLcys1AAdvADJbZMC+bAQYAhZNDJZMjEjHPJi4o3opFvIAdiqah0dsgH5OyJAqlKkfBgtx81l5HT0AOXcHAD4WagAGFInUs2mhFA0eHU1ZNYBtAF0WCIBzLiapExbwyMz87y1qAxGpZ5YAK28Cy+kzSQmoAE5NH9gds0rJIZoVK9lAYAHSGTbmMb0bEMZgsRJcGpsMB6KyefGzfR+Fg+IA===), `fixed (Foo* p = &fooRef)` is actually the same as `Foo* p = &foo`, because they both use the `ldloca.N` instruction to load the address of the variable and then use the `conv.u` instruction to convert the address to a pointer type and assign it to the pointer variable.

As mentioned earlier, variables on the stack are always fixed, which means that a pointer to this variable is valid as long as it does not exceed the scope. The following usage is safe:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo = new() { i = 1 };
    ref var fooRef = ref foo;
    Foo* ptr;
    fixed (Foo* p = &fooRef)
        ptr = p;
    M(ptr);
}

static void M(Foo* ptr) => Console.WriteLine((*ptr).i); // print correct value
ref struct Foo { public int i; }
```

On the contrary, you should avoid using this pointer outside of the scope like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pfoo = M(1);
    var j = N();
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    Console.WriteLine((*pfoo).i); // print strange value
}

static Foo* M(int i)
{
    Foo foo = new() { i = i };
    ref var fooRef = ref foo;
    fixed (Foo* ptr = &fooRef)
        return ptr;
}

static int N() => 10;
```

Similarly, managed pointers are not always safe, as in the example above, you can return a local variable as `ref`, but the difference is that the compiler will issue a warning (or error when unsafe keyword is not used).

```
static unsafe ref Foo M(int i)
{
    var foo = new Foo { i = i };
    return ref foo; // CS9091
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realized I posted the wrong initial code. The fixed statement is needed to take the address of a `ref` to the `ref struct`. I believe that'd because `ref`s are *all* implemented as managed pointers.

Comment: It shouldn't be needed, see this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1792

Comment: Thank you for the helpful edits as well. Initially I thought that in my `ref struct` type, the captured pointer should always be valid since it can only reference other `ref struct`s which must also be valid for the entire life of the child node. I'm going to try a couple of scenarios that might break that assumption.